# xcrun fails with zip I/O error: No such file or directory zip error:

Tags: xcode

Trying to export an archive with xcrun

```
xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication \
    -v $BUILD_PATH/$PRODUCT_NAME.xcarchive/Products/Applications/$PROJECT_NAME.app \
    -o $BUILD_PATH/$PRODUCT_NAME.ipa
```

Fails with the following error:

```
+ /usr/bin/zip --symlinks --verbose --recurse-paths ../xx/xx.ipa . Program /usr/bin/zip returned 15 : [zip I/O error: No such file or directory zip error: Could not create output file (../xx/xx.ipa) ]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

xcrun require absolute paths. (i.e. /User/you/...).  You can do $PWD/build/release-iphoneos/etc.

Comment: life saver, who knew that it had to be absolute?!